# Setup for NEW HDD?

Tags: hard-drive, bios, setup

Building my FIRST computer. Will start with at least - one HDD, I purchased a WD SATA HDD a 10,000RPM VelociRaptor 500GB.

I have read that if you use one of the settings, can't remember what it's called, that it would make an HDD rund at IDE speeds???

Could I or should I run it in RAID instead? Is RAID only for more than one HDD/ssd?
I would like to get like a 64GB SSD later to maybe speed things up working together.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I have read that if you use one of the settings, can't remember what it's called, that it would make an HDD rund at IDE speeds?

I suspect that you refer to AHCI.

Modern PCs usually come with a SATA connector and the ability to run both in the normal AHCI mode or in legacy IDE mode. AHCI had advantage, such as hot plugging and command queuing. There is also a performenance difference, though this usually rather small.

There is not reason not to run in AHCI mode unless you got an OS which only understands old fashioned IDE mode (e.g. win 3.1, or XP without drivers).

> Could I or should I run it in RAID instead? Is RAID only for more than one HDD/ssd?

RAID is a way to run **multiple** disks as one. With a single disk RAID makes no sense.

For a simple description as what to RAID is, please see [this post](http://serverfault.com/questions/339128/what-are-the-different-widely-used-raid-levels-and-when-should-i-consider-them).